# Julia : Dataframes packages having trouble to convert column containing both int and float

Tags: dataframe, julia, juno-ide

I'm a `R` user with great interest for `Julia`. I don't have a computer science background. I just tried to read a 'csv' file in `Juno` with the following command:

```julia
using CSV
using DataFrames

df = CSV.read(joinpath(Pkg.dir("DataFrames"), 
"path/to/database.csv"));
```

and got the following error message

```julia
CSV.CSVError('error parsing a 'Int64' value on column 26, row 289; encountered '.'"
in read at CSV/src/Source.jl:294
in #read#29 at CSV/src/Source.jl:299
in stream! at DataStreams/src/DataStreams.jl:145
in stream!#5 at DataStreams/src/DataStreams.jl:151
in stream! at DataStreams/src/DataStreams.jl:187
in streamto! at DataStreams/src/DataStreams.jl:173
in streamfrom at CSV/src/Source.jl:195
in paresefield at CSV/src/paresefield.jl:107
in paresefield at CSV/src/paresefield.jl:127
in checknullend at CSV/src/paresefield.jl:56
```

I look at the entry indicated in the data frame: the row 287, 288 are like this `30`, `33` respectively (seem to be of type `Integer`) and the the row 289 is `30.445` (which is of type `float`).

Is the problem that `DataFrames` filling the column with `Int` and stopped when it saw an `Float`?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Would you make a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  I want to see it for myself.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @rickhg12hs. I just tried to create a MCVE but this theory didn't work (there was no problem importing the data from the MCVE with entry `30, 31, 32, 22.51234` from the csv). But the fact remain that this is the pattern encountered at the row indicated by Julia. As it is a research database, I cannot put it on the internet sorry. Accordingly I removed the last phrase of the question.

Comment: For example, `io = IOBuffer("1,2,3,4\n5,6,7,8\n9,10,11,12\n13,14.2,15,16");df=CSV.read(io, datarow=1)` works fine for me.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you try `df = CSV.read(joinpath(Pkg.dir("DataFrames"), "path/to/database.csv"), datarow=289)`?

Comment: There is the following error output: `function joinpath does not accept keyword arguments [1] kwfunc(::Any) at ./boot.jl:237 [2] eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:235 [3] eval(::Any) at ./boot.jl:234 [4] macro expansion at /Applications/JuliaPro-0.6.2.2.app/Contents/Resources/pkgs-0.6.2.2/v0.6/Atom/src/repl.jl:117 [inlined]`
 [5] anonymous at ./<missing>:?

Comment: I think there's a `(` and/or `)` placement error.  What I mean to try is `df = CSV.read(wherever/your/CSV/is, datarow=289)`.

Comment: Ok sorry. I got the following error message `ERROR: CSV.CSVError("error parsing a 'Int64' value on column 9, row 112; encountered 'N'")`

Comment: Are you confident about this file's CSV format?  Does `readdlm` show similar problems?

Comment: I'm confident that this file is at CSV format. I generated this file after cleaning up a data base with R using command `write.csv()`. I had no trouble re-opening it with the command `read.csv()` in R. It's size is 811 x 105 if it helps. I tried the command `readdlm("path/to/file.csv") in Julia but got the following error message: ` ERROR: unexpected character ',' after quoted field at row 1 column 1`

Comment: I'd try with the new CSV.jl release tagged a few days ago, it should be much more robust regarding type detection.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that float happens too late in the data set. By default CSV.jl uses `rows_for_type_detect` value equal to `100`. Which means that only first 100 rows are used to determine the type of a column in the output. Set `rows_for_type_detect` keyword parameter in `CSV.read` to e.g. `300` and all should work correctly.

Alternatively you can pass `types` keyword argument to manually set column type (in this case `Float64` for this column would be appropriate).

Comment: @ Thank you very much @BogumilKaminsky. That solved the problem indeed. However as the problem persisted after setting `rows_for_type_detect = 300` I set it to 811 (the length of the database). This time it worked but it took a good 26.8 seconds according to the command `@time df = CSV.read("path/tofile.csv")`. Isn't there a way to read a csv file more easily and efficiently (cf command `read.csv("path/tofile.csv")` of R which takes 0.023 sec (1000x faster) without having to specify a particular number of row)?