# How to decrease the time taken to open a large csv file in Julia (using CSV and DataFrames)?

Tags: csv, dataframe, julia, processing-efficiency, memory-efficient

I'm a `R` user with great interest for `Julia` and strongly willing to switch to `Julia` on the long term. I looked for a large csv file on the internet and found this [website of US government](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?res_format=CSV) and downloaded the `College Scorecard` dataset. I  tried to read a 'csv' file in `Juno` with the following command:

```julia
using CSV
using DataFrames

@time df = CSV.read("/Path/to/Most-Recent-Cohorts-Scorecard-Elements.csv", rows_for_type_detect = 7175);
```

I got the following output:

```julia
212.333866 seconds (43.84 M allocations: 2.244 GiB, 0.25% gc time)
```

I inserted the line `rows_for_type_detect = 7175` because otherwise I get an error message an cannot open the file. See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52470225/julia-dataframes-packages-having-trouble-to-convert-column-containing-both-int/52473615#52473615) for why it might happen

When doing the same operation in `R` with

```julia
start_time <- Sys.time()
df_try = read.csv("/Path/to/Most-Recent-Cohorts-Scorecard-Elements.csv")
end_time <- Sys.time()
end_time - start_time
```

I get the following output

```julia
Time difference of 0.3337972 secs
```

Is there a way to read large dataframe more efficiently in `Julia`?

**MAJOR EDIT**

As pointed out by  @BogumiłKamiński, this difference between `R` and `Julia` for this particular task **LARGELY DECREASES** when using the newest version of `Julia` and `CSV`. So please read my message above (which I frankly hesitated to simply delete) with a significant grain of salt and read the comment of Bogumił Kamiński!  And a big thank you to all developers who take from their free time to build and improve a wonderful language like `Julia` for free!

**EDIT N°2**

now when performing

```julia
@time df = CSV.read(joinpath("/path/to/file.csv"))
```

Here are the result

```julia
0.184593 seconds (223.44 k allocations: 5.321 MiB)
```

Brilliant! Thank you @Bogumił Kamiński!

Comment: I will answer here (as you have asked a similar question in the other thread). I have tested this file and on my Julia and R. R takies 1.2 second and Julia takes 2.3 second on the first call and 1.4 second on the second call (differences due to precompilation), so they are comparable. CSV.jl has undergone significant improvements over last few weeks. I recommend you to wait till a new release of CSV.jl is tagged (probably in a few days) or use master version of the package `add CSV#master`.

Comment: Dear @BogumiłKamiński. Thank you very much for your answer. You're totally right: I actually ran the code above with an old version of `Julia`: `Julia-Pro-Juno-0.6.2.2`. When running the code with `Julia 1.0`, it takes 9.6 seconds the first call and 1.4 seconds the second call. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably try using https://github.com/queryverse/CSVFiles.jl

This package provides load and save support for CSV Files under the [FileIO.jl](https://github.com/JuliaIO/FileIO.jl) package.

It's part of [Queryverse ecosystem](https://github.com/queryverse/Queryverse.jl).

```
using CSVFiles, DataFrames
fname = "/Path/to/Most-Recent-Cohorts-Scorecard-Elements.csv"
df = DataFrame(load(fname))
```

but as Bogumił Kamiński suggested, maybe simply using latest master version of CSV.jl could help to improve performances but I think that being aware of this quite new Queryverse universe is something important for the Julia community.

If you have to load several time the same big file, maybe you should consider an other kind of format because textual data is quite long to process. A binary format with compressing may be something you should consider if fast loading is really important for you.

Maybe you should have a look at:

- https://github.com/JuliaIO/HDF5.jl
- https://github.com/JuliaIO/JLD.jl
- https://github.com/JuliaIO/JLD2.jl
- https://github.com/JuliaComputing/Parquet.jl
- https://github.com/JuliaData/Feather.jl

Comment: What's the relationship between csv.jl and csvfiles.jl? Which one is faster? Which one should I use if I want to stream a large dataset that doesn't fit on memory? (for example to later use it with OnlineStats?